# How delete margin-bottom on last line blocks?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, margin

I have i collection of tags: 
[image]

How to switch off margin-bottom on line 3 or if tags is 100 or 200 or 300?

Code example:

I create collections of tags. It could be a 1 element or more.

```
<div class="collection">
  <div class="tag">1</div>
  <div class="tag">2</div>
  <div class="tag">3</div>
  <div class="tag">4</div>
  <div class="tag">5</div>
  <div class="tag">6</div>
  <div class="tag">7</div>
  <div class="tag">8</div>
  <div class="tag">9</div>
  [...or more]
  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

SASS example

```
.collection
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 20px; 
 
.tag
  width: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  
.footer
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: blue;
  width: 900px;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
```

Comment: Can we see your code?

If you have the specific class/element tags of each element from Line 3, you can just add `margin-bottom: 0;` to all three of them (or their parent container).

Comment: `:nth-child(n+6):nth-child(-n+10)` this code take **tag 7, tag 8, and tag 9**
then add  `margin-bottom: 0;`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4axwpbzu/22/

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] **in your question**, not on jsFiddle.

Comment: @RayeesAC items might be 9 or 20 or 30 or more. Its, need to be at last line.

Comment: `nth-child(n+7):nth-child(-n+9)` try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

`nth-child` use to select between **tag 7** to **tag 9**

```
.tag:nth-child(n+7):nth-child(-n+9){
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
 }
```

```css
.collection{
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 20px; 
 }
.tag{
  width: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
 .tag:nth-child(n+7):nth-child(-n+9){
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
 }
.footer{
  background: blue;
  width: 900px;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="collection">
  <div class="tag">1</div>
  <div class="tag">2</div>
  <div class="tag">3</div>
  <div class="tag">4</div>
  <div class="tag">5</div>
  <div class="tag">6</div>
  <div class="tag">7</div>
  <div class="tag">8</div>
  <div class="tag">9</div>
  
  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I remove footer `margin-top`. because it shows the `margin-bottom` to recognize.

Comment: Please check now @YourBuddy

Comment: Sorry, tags could be 1 or 10 or 30. What would be needed between the footer and tags i have one margin

Comment: i just remove margin-top to recongine there is no margin-bottom after the tags 7,8 and 9

Comment: `.tag:first-child, .tag:nth-child(10), .tag:nth-child(30){  margin-bottom: 0 !important;  }`

Answer (score -1):

You can always use below tag on the elements of row 3.
margin-bottom: 0;
Please share more details/ your code if not clear.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4axwpbzu/22/